# express dynamic routing to handle /a/b-c-d-:e-:f

Tags: javascript, express

my route looks like this:

```
server.get("/something/best-shoes-in-india-:brand-:location", (req, res) => {
   res.send(JSON.stringify(req.params))

})
```

brand name = addidas, location = delhi

if the url is => "/something/best-shoes-in-india-addidas-delhi
it gives => {
 brand: addidas,
 location: delhi
} which is correct but

if brand name is => addi das, location = delhi
then the url is => "/something/best-shoes-in-india-addi-das-delhi

it gives => {
 brand: addi,
 location: das-delhi
}

how to get addi-das as brand name in this case?`enter code here`

Answer (score 1):

You should handle like this.

```
server.get("/something/best-shoes-in-india-/:brand/:location", (req, res) => {
  const { brand, location } = req.params;
  console.log(brand, location);
  res.send(JSON.stringify(req.params))
});
```

req.params.brand will have the brand
req.params.location will have the location

Comment: Thank You, Sayooj for the help.
And is there any other way so that it is not nested as /:brand:location ?

Comment: No you have pass it as two params. Otherwise you need to pass as a single argument and split it.but it is not a good aprroach